# Read PHP SESSION cookies from a subdomain

Tags: php, cookies

I have an SSO system created with PHP `$_SESSION cookies`. It's working fine, almost. It logs in fine, but it's missing the key of the `$_SESSION` key. It's in the cookie list, but my domain cannot read the subdomain's (login.website.com) `$_SESSION` cookie. Here's how it works. Person logs into domain through subdomain. Subdomain is correct, so it redirects. It puts the $_SESSION cookie in the list for login.website.com, so I assume it will read it. I try to let PHP use it, but it just don't work.

Comment: What did you set the session cookie domain to? Cookies from a subdomain are not automatically available for the “main” domain, unless you explicitly make it so.

Comment: You can't set the session cookie to a different domain, can you?

Comment: Not for totally different ones, but from a subdomain you should be able to set it so that it is valid for the main domain as well.